# If $f \in V^*$, $f(\alpha) = \beta^T\alpha$ for some $b \in V$ then $\|f\| = \|\beta\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

This is based on Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis. Let $(V, \|\cdot\|_{V})$ be a normed finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbf{R}$. Define norm $\| \cdot \|_{V^*}$ on $V^*$ by putting $\| f \|_{V^*} = \inf\{\, b \in \mathbf{R}\,\mid\, \forall\alpha \in V : |f(\alpha)| \leq b\| \alpha\|_{V}\}$. Let $\beta \in V$ be a unique vector such that $\forall\alpha \in V : f(\alpha) = \beta^{\mathrm{T}}\alpha$. Then $\| f \|_{V^*} = \| \beta \|_V$.

I guess I'm asking for clarification. I can prove this with Schwarz inequality if $\|\cdot\|_V$ is the usual Euclidean norm (which is what Rudin asks for). But looking at other norms, like the maximum norm on $V$ or the $\|\cdot\|_p$ norms, it seems to be true too. I've looked for a counterexample, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Just to clarify, is $V$ $\Bbb{R}^n$ for some $n$? If not, then what does the transpose of an abstract vector $\beta$ mean?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add $\beta \in V$. Yeah, $V$ is $\mathbf{R}^n$ up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

If we equip $V = \Bbb{R}^n$ with an arbitrary norm $\| \cdot \|$, then there definitely will be some unique $\beta \in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $f(\alpha) = \beta^\top \alpha$, but it may not satisfy $\|f\|_{V^*} = \|\beta\|$. We can construct $\beta$ very easily as
$$\beta = \begin{bmatrix} f(e_1) & f(e_2) & \cdots & f(e_n)\end{bmatrix}^\top,$$
where $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$. Note that this formula is completely independent of norm!

Consider the infinity-norm (i.e. the max norm) on $\Bbb{R}^2$, and the functional
$$f(x, y) = x + y.$$
Then $\beta = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^\top$,
$$|f(x, y)| = |x + y| \le |x| + |y| \le 2\|(x, y)\|_\infty,$$
and $f(1, 1) = 1 + 1 = 2\|(1, 1)\|_\infty$. Therefore, $\|f\|_{V^*} = 2$. But, $\|\beta\|_\infty = 1 \neq 2$, so we have a counterexample.

---

As it turns out, the standard Euclidean norm is the *only* norm which satisfies this particular theorem for $V = \Bbb{R}^n$! Indeed, if the result holds for norm $\| \cdot \|$, then for any $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb{R}^n$,
$$\|\beta\|\|\alpha\| = \|f\|_{V^*} \|\alpha\| \ge f(\alpha) = \beta^\top \alpha,$$
where $f \in V^*$ corresponds to $\beta$. If we take $\alpha = \beta$, then we get
$$\|\beta\|^2 \ge \beta^\top \beta = \|\beta\|_2^2 \implies \|\beta\| \ge \|\beta\|_2.$$
Now, let $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $\|\alpha\| = 1$ and $f(\alpha) = \|f\|_{V^*}\|\alpha\|$. Note that $\alpha \neq 0$, so $\|\alpha\|_2 > 0$. By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$\|\beta\| \|\alpha\| = \beta^\top \alpha \le \|\beta\|_2 \|\alpha\|_2 \le \|\beta\|_2 \|\alpha\| \le \|\beta\| \|\alpha\|.$$
Therefore,
$$\|\beta\| \|\alpha\| = \|\beta\|_2 \|\alpha\| \implies \|\beta\| = \|\beta\|_2.$$
This holds generally, for $\beta \in \Bbb{R}^n$, hence the norm must be the Euclidean norm.